# Can someone fix this code?

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error

```
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(0,1000,60):
        if sayi % i == 0:

            print "Şu an"+ sayi/60+". dakikaya girdik." 
    print "Şu an %s'nci saniyedeyiz." % str(sayi)
    sayi = sayi +1
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

And even after I changed that it still gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 4, in <module>
    if sayi % i == 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: 1. What did you change to the fix the first error? 2. Given that `i` starts as `0`, what precisely don't you understand about the second error?

Comment: This isn't a site for bulk code correction or tutoring. Users must display an attempt at research and have a directed question when asking on this site, not just blocks of code without any specific purpose in the post. When asking next, consider asking about a specific line or a paradigm you don't understand.

Comment: I fixed the first code like this

Comment: while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(0,1000,60):
            if sayi % i == 0:
                
                print "Şu an"+ sayi/60+". dakikaya girdik." 
        print "Şu an %s'nci saniyedeyiz." % str(sayi)
        sayi = sayi +1

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start your for loop from `1`, not `0`. It is mathematically and programmatically illegal to divide by 0.

Change the line of your for loop to this:

`for i in range(1,1000,60):`

You code shouldn't crash (at least for this reason) after this change.